# algebraic closures (model -theory)

Tags: model-theory

I try to prove this lemma : 
Let be N a saturated model. Let be $ \phi(x) $ a consistent formula with parameters in $A$ and $b\in N$ .  If for all $a$ such that $ \phi(a) $ I have $b\in acl(A,a), $then $b\in acl(A) $ .Some help to prove this lemma?

Comment: It is strange to write Acl$(C)$ instead of acl$(C)$ .... but beside that I don't see anything wrong. Open any modern book in model theory to find the context. Maybe the question is just too much (model-theory) to be tagged (logic). Then just delete the tag.

Comment: I see that in trying to provide more context you changed the question quite a bit (imho the previous question was sharper). So, leave aside  the messy context. I think you are asking the following. If $\phi(x)$ is over $A$ and $B$ is a finite set such that for every $a\models\phi(x)$ there is a $b\in B$ such that $b\in$acl$(A,a)$ is $B\subseteq$acl$(A)$? Or at least $B\cap$acl$(A)\neq\varnothing$? I would suggest to post a new question.

Comment: first of all thank you very much ! You have perfectly identified my goal . I have to edit/ modified this question or do I create a new one in the way you suggest?

Comment: It is better (imho, of course) to return to the original question. So it will match with the answer for the sake readers in the future. Then post a new question (this has been put on hold by error).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question lives in a large saturated model. By your assumptions the type $\{\phi(x)\wedge\psi(b,x)\wedge\exists^{=n+1}y\ \psi(y,x)\ :\ \psi(y,x)\in L(A),\ n\in\omega\}$ is inconsistent. Apply compactness. The formula that witnesses $b\in Acl(A)$ is obtained by (lengthy) straightforward manipulations.

There is also a much shorter argument (but it requires some background): every model containing $A$ contains a solution of $\phi(x)$ hence it contains $b$.